# Jquery UL LI elements, $.each to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

Can't figure out what this isn't working right. Trying to get each button_select_sub li's text and put it in an array. Its being built to find the #button_groupings children like it is, cause the functionality behind it is based on the notion that there will be multiple instances of the HTML below. The problem I am having right now is, not so much as it getting the text from each, but however its pushing it into the array is making the array just 1 item, not multiple items.

```
$('#button_groupings').children('li').children('.button_select_sub').each(function(n,v){listArray.push($(this).text());})
```

The html for it.

```
<div class="button_select_header_like_thing">
    <div class="button_select">
        <ul class="button_select_toggle" id="button_groupings">
            <li>
                <div class="button_select_text">Menu Text</div><div class="button_select_arrow">V</div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="button_select_sub" rel="hidden">
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                </ul>       
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `var listArray;` line somewhere in the global scope? If not, the variable would probably be treated as a local variable to that anonymous function.

**Edit**

It looks like you need to go one level deeper before doing the each(). You're doing .each on the <ul class='button_select_sub'> element, instead of the li element.

```
$('#button_groupings').children('li').children('.button_select_sub').children('li').each(function(n,v){listArray.push($(this).text());})
```

You can also use this slightly easier to read syntax.

```
$('#button_groupings li .button_select_sub li').each(function(n,v){
    listArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: yea, sorry right above the each() I have listArray = new Array();